# Equivalent function inputs

Tags: functions

$$f\left(x-\frac 1x\right) = x^3-\frac 1{x^3}\implies f(-x) = \,?$$

I can't think of anything considering that the input of the function that we already know its definition is not $x$ but a composite.

Comment: Hint:  note that for each $y$ there is a unique $x>0$ such that $x-\frac 1x=y$

Answer (score 1):

After

$$
\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^3 = x^3-\frac{1}{x^3}-3\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$

we have

$$
x-\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{3}\left(f\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right)
$$

or

$$
y = \frac{1}{3}\left(f(y)-y^3\right)
$$

then

$$
f(-x) = -(3+x^2)x
$$

Answer (score 0):

Write $t=x-1/x$ then 
$$ t^3 =x^3-3x+3/x-1/x^3 = f(t)-3t$$ 
so 
$$f(t) = t^3+3t\implies f(-t)=-t^3+3t$$

Notice that $x\mapsto x-1/x$ is also surjective from  $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)=(a-b)((a-b)^2+3ab).$$

Note that:
$$\begin{align}f\left(x-\frac 1x\right) &= x^3-\frac 1{x^3}=\left(x-\frac1x\right)\left(\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+3\right) \Rightarrow \\
f(x)&=x(x^2+3) \Rightarrow \\
f(-x)&=-x(x^2+3).\end{align}$$